# Chart Title inexplicably disappearing

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a macro that is creating a chart on each tab in a given workbook (after doing some other things). As a part of that, the chart is supposed to have a title added, with the title set to the sheet name. Below is how I tried to do that:

```
S.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & S.Name & "!$H$1"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & S.Name & "!$H$2:$H$" & i
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & S.Name & "!$G$2:$G$" & i
temp = 0
Do While ActiveChart.HasTitle = False
    If temp <= 5 Then
        ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
        temp = temp + 1
    Else
        MsgBox "The script failed to add a title to the chart on " & S.Name
    End If
Loop
If ActiveChart.HasTitle Then
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = S.Name
End If
```

For context, i is the last row of data for that sheet (dynamically set based on the number of data points on that sheet), and S is a Worksheet variable holding the current sheet, temp is just an all purpose counter I added to prevent an infinite loop.

The thing that really gets me is that the error occurs on the second to last line in the snippet above. For the macro to have even gotten there, there had to have been a chart title. But then the error thrown says there isn't one.

The error doesn't occur if I step through the code above each time, but turning screenupdates back on and activating S does not prevent the error.

So it seems like there's some context that's not handled by the code correctly, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the specific error message?

Comment: Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': This object has no title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I ultimately went with follows. All the credit to Jimmy Smith and David Zemens though, they got me here, just wanted to capture end state for anyone who finds this page in the future

```
Dim ch as ChartObject

Set ch = S.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("J2").Left, Top:=Range("J2").Top, Width:=500, Height:=325)
ch.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & S.Name & "!$H$1"
ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & S.Name & "!$H$2:$H$" & i
ch.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & S.Name & "!$G$2:$G$" & i
ch.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
temp = 0
Do While ch.Chart.HasTitle = False
    If temp <= 5 Then
        ch.Chart.HasTitle = True
        temp = temp + 1
    Else
        MsgBox "The script failed to add a title to the chart on " & S.Name
    End If
Loop
If ch.Chart.HasTitle Then
    ch.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = S.Name
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd need the specific error, but I've had weird quirks with selected/Active objects.  If that's a reference to the chart then you should be able to replace those ActiveChart references with "S". Depending on your version of Excel it may be S.Chart.SeriesCollection...

Something to test, see 'this line

```
Dim cht as Chart

Set cht = S.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Chart
cht.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart) 'this line
cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & S.Name & "!$H$1"
cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & S.Name & "!$H$2:$H$" & i
cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & S.Name & "!$G$2:$G$" & i
temp = 0
Do While cht.HasTitle = False
    If temp <= 5 Then
        cht.HasTitle = True
        temp = temp + 1
    Else
        MsgBox "The script failed to add a title to the chart on " & S.Name
    End If
Loop
If cht.HasTitle Then
    cht.ChartTitle.Text = S.Name
End If
```

[taken from here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/563058-interesting-visual-basic-applications-problem.html)

Comment: `S` is a reference to the worksheet object. My thoughts along the same line, though -- I've revised your answer with that idea: OP should declare a variable to represent the chart object, and refer to that, rather than `ActiveChart`.

Comment: The suggestion you had above, unfortunately, did not prevent the error.

Comment: @JMichael please try the revised answer.

Comment: Using a ChartObject did though. Code is in separate answer (too long for comment)